# Выбор формы для открытия при запуске

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть два окна в проекте: `Form1` и `Form2`. Сначала была создана `form2` и, соответственно, она открывается при запуске приложения первой. Мне необходимо, чтобы сначала открывалась `Form1`. Как это настроить?

Comment: _Не очень трудным_ вопрос будет при наличии соответствующего кода в вопросе.

Comment: а зачем код то? я же говорю есть две формы как сделать приоритетной первую форму! кода нету! я просто создал две формы одна из них добавляет что то ее я создал первой а сейчас мне просто нужна как бы главная форма вот и все

Comment: Формы ведь не из воздуха берутся.

Answer (score 9):

Загляните в самый главный `.cs` файл проекта и увидите там строку

```
Application.Run(new FormName());
```

Собственно, здесь и можно поменять название формы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Блин огромное вам спасибо! Выручили очень! Теперь я понял как! Очень вам благодарен!

Comment: Везде бы таких как вы что бы объясняли)

Comment: @Ildarik07 поставьте галочку рядом с ответом, чтобы было ясно, что вопрос исчерпан

Comment: @Ildarik07 скажем прямо: никто не отменял возможность того, что у вас в коде инициализация форм происходит по-другому. Dmi7ry рискнул (взял наиболее вероятный вариант), угадал - хорошо. Если бы код из `Program.cs` (или как у вас называется этот файл) был представлен в вопросе - и гадать бы не пришлось.

Comment: @Regent да, предположил, что если человек задаёт такой вопрос, то он, скорее всего, в код запуска приложения и создания формы, никогда ни заглядывал (и, с большой вероятностью, не подозревал о его существовании :) )

Comment: @Dmi7ry да, меня те же мысли посещали, но создавать весь пример с нуля у меня желания не возникло :) Остаётся лишь надеяться, что автор, по крайней мере, отметит ответ как правильный.