# Как запустить форму windows forms designer не запуская программу?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Работаю на C# в Visual studio 2019.

В конкретный момент, чтобы посмотреть как выглядит форма для пользователя, необходимо запускать программу (F5). Мне нужно запустить только форму, без запуска программы, посмотреть как лежат элементы, как растягивается форма и так далее. Подобное у меня получалось в visual studio 2010, когда изучал windows forms, но я забыл сочетание клавиш.

Фича очень редкая (гуглил - инфы нуль), но полезная, так как, чтобы добраться до определенный формы, мне  не нужно открывать множество форм перед ней а запускаю непосредственно ее.

Давайте объясню на картинках.

1. Вот форма, которая отображается в дезайнере, и я могу на нее перетаскивать различные элементы. Программа не запущена.
   [image: Форма в дизайнере]
2. Вот та же форма, только уже запущенная с помощью программы. Но мне, чтобы добраться до нее, нужно открыть несколько форм до нее.
   [image: Форма, при запущенной программы]
3. Проблема вот в чем. Мне нужно всего лишь посмотреть как растягивается форма, как лежат кнопки и так далее. Программа не должна запускается, то есть кнопка F5 как на первом скриншоте а не как на втором (то есть никакого конструктора и соединение с базой данных у меня не должно запускаться как на втором скриншоте). Я помню, запускалась отдельно форма, и даже если в коде у меня что то кнопка делала, то в данном режиме она ничего не делала, так как сама программа не запущена и никакие события естественно не посылались.

Пометили мой вопрос как дубликат вот этого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431177/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5). Это вообще не похоже на мою тему, так как там рассматривается выбор запуска первой формы когда запускается программа. В моем случае мне нужно протестировать форму без запуска программы. Посмотреть как выглядит UI не через дизайнер и не через запуск программы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выбор формы для открытия при запуске](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431177/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: Не помню такого сочетания ни в какой из версий Visual Studio (2005-2019).  Сложно представить как такое будет работать в общем случае, ведь форма часто зависит от внешних факторов (переданных в конструктор формы параметров, настроенного соединения с БД и т.п.). Насколько я знаю единственный способ это изменять стартовую форму всего приложения (ответ дан в дубликате).

Comment: Или я не понял вопроса и проблема в том, что у Вас форма не отображается в дизайнере форм? Тогда распишите подробнее что происходит если нажать правой клавишей на форму и выбрать «View designer» (или в коде формы нажать Shift+F7).

Comment: @defaultlocale я обновил описание. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: +1  за старание, голос за закрытие я отозвал :) Тем не менее я правильно понял вопрос и до сих пор с трудом представляю такую функцию. Поиск тоже ничего не дал. Может Вы изучали winforms на C++, там есть некий [Dialog Editor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/dialog-editor?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @defaultlocale Я помню точно, смотрел видео(кажется от ITVDN) по изучению языка C# и рассматривали winforms. Внезапно он сказал некое сочетание клавиш (что то связанное с клавишами Ctrl, R, хотя могу и ошибаться). Некоторое время я пользовался ими, и потом необходимость ушла в windows forms. Сейчас не могу ни клавиши вспомнить, не видео найти да и гугл не помогает.

Comment: Я тоже могу сказать, что такой возможности в стандартной Студии никогда не было и нет. Возможно, у вас было установлено какое-то хитрое стороннее дополнение? Возможно, ваше решение (solution) состояло из нескольких проектов? И вы запускали конкретный проект с нужной формой?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да нет же. Ничего стороннего у меня не было. Мое решение состояло из одного проекта winforms C#.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить следующее.

В Solution Explorer делаете правый клик на вашем проекте, в контекстном меню выбираете Initialize Interactive with Project.

Откроется окно интерактивных команд с подключенными всеми необходимыми сборками и пространствами имён.

В этом окне можете набрать команду показа нужной формы:

```
new SettingTeamForm().Show();
```

После нажатия Enter форма должна появиться.

Естественно, в конструктор нужно передать необходимые параметры, если они есть.

Подробнее можно посмотреть в этой [теме](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11135571/5045688), со скриншотами.
Кстати, ещё можно попробовать использовать Immediate Window, но у меня этот способ глючит.